# Machine Learning using mahout- Decision tree

Tags: mahout

I am trying to build a decision tree using mahout and would be really helpful if some one can help me on this. Given below is my requirement:

1. I am trying to build this as part of a medical diagnosis problem and should ask questions and subsequent questions should be based on the initial question. For example:
   (a) if asked the question "do you have cold?" and if the answer is "Yes" then next question would be "Do you have Fever?"
2. Can some one help me guide on this as to how such a thing is possible using mahout ?
3. I read some where that once a model is built, the model can be used in a web application to display these questions. Please advice.

regards,
Deepak.

Comment: wrt question 3.: _I read some where that once a model is built, the model can be used in a web application to display these questions_. It is certainly possible to persist a model once it is built see the m (Lyubimov & Palumbo 2016) chapter 8.

Comment: Thanks. Are you mentioning about the book "Apache Mahout: Beyond Mapreduce "?

Comment: Also is the example based on mahout and java